# Compare per row values in four different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DEC': ['Food','Kyl','Food','Fashion'], 
                   'JAN': ['Food','Kyl','Kyl','Food'],
                   'FEB': ['Food','Kyl','Kyl','Food'],
                   'MAR': ['Food','Kyl','Kyl','Fashion'],
                   'COUNTS': [4988, 1976, 797, 613]})

DEC     JAN     FEB     MAR     COUNTS
Food    Food    Food    Food    4988
Kyl     Kyl     Kyl     Kyl     1976
Food    Kyl     Kyl     Kyl     797
Fashion Food    Food    Fashion 613
```

What I want to do is make a per row comparison of the four columns DEC-MAR and create a new column that outputs either the value if they are all the same, or the two-three-four values in case of differences.

So, the desired output DataFrame is

```
DEC     JAN     FEB     MAR     COUNTS   COMPARISON
Food    Food    Food    Food    4988     Food
Kyl     Kyl     Kyl     Kyl     1976     Kyl
Food    Kyl     Kyl     Kyl     797      Food-Kyl
Fashion Food    Food    Fashion 61       Fashion-Food
```

I thought I could do it by defining a function which uses `np.where` and makes the comparisons, but there are so many comparisons to go through that it wouldn't be efficient (i.e. Col1==Col2 or Col1==Col3 or Col1==Col4 or Col2==Cole3 etc....)

This is what I started but gave up due to all the manual work, hoping for a better solution:

```
def group_combs(row):
    if (row['DEC'] == row['JAN']) & 
    (row['DEC'] == row['JAN']) & 
    (row['DEC'] == row['JAN']):
        val = row['DEC']
        
        
    elif row['FEB'] == row['MAR']:
        val = row['FEB']
    else:
        val = -1
    return val
```

Is there a better way to do this other than comparing all columns manually?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension for deduplicated join values for improve performance:

```
df['COMPARISON'] = ['-'.join(dict.fromkeys(x))for x in df.drop('COUNTS', axis=1).to_numpy()]
print (df)
       DEC   JAN   FEB      MAR  COUNTS    COMPARISON
0     Food  Food  Food     Food    4988          Food
1      Kyl   Kyl   Kyl      Kyl    1976           Kyl
2     Food   Kyl   Kyl      Kyl     797      Food-Kyl
3  Fashion  Food  Food  Fashion     613  Fashion-Food
```

**Timings**:

```
#4k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [135]: %timeit df['COMPARISON'] = (df.drop(columns='COUNTS').agg(lambda s: '-'.join(dict.fromkeys(s)), axis=1))
176 ms ± 6.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [136]: %timeit df['COMPARISON'] = ['-'.join(dict.fromkeys(x)) for x in df.drop('COUNTS', axis=1).to_numpy()]
15.9 ms ± 2.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
#40k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [138]: %timeit df['COMPARISON'] = (df.drop(columns='COUNTS').agg(lambda s: '-'.join(dict.fromkeys(s)), axis=1))
1.68 s ± 10.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [139]: %timeit df['COMPARISON'] = ['-'.join(dict.fromkeys(x))for x in df.drop('COUNTS', axis=1).to_numpy()]
87.7 ms ± 4.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the unwanted columns with `drop` and aggregate the unique values (in order) with `groupby`+`agg` and `dict.fromkeys`, then `join` them back:

```
df['COMPARISON'] = (df
                   .drop(columns='COUNTS')
                   .agg(lambda s: '-'.join(dict.fromkeys(s)), axis=1)
                   )
```

output:

```
       DEC   JAN   FEB      MAR  COUNTS    COMPARISON
0     Food  Food  Food     Food    4988          Food
1      Kyl   Kyl   Kyl      Kyl    1976           Kyl
2     Food   Kyl   Kyl      Kyl     797      Food-Kyl
3  Fashion  Food  Food  Fashion     613  Fashion-Food
```